# Is TGA analysis required for composites used in low speed subsonic aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-structures, composite-materials

I need to analyse the temperature drop effects on glass-fiber reinforced polymer ([GFRP](http://www-lmdc.insa-toulouse.fr/cost534/COST534-PPT/PDF/monday-am/Gulikers.pdf)) used in aircraft subjected to icing, how can  it be done?

Does thermogravimetric analysis ([TGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermogravimetric_analysis)) help or is it only for high temperature material?